# how to convert quarterly data to monthly

Tags: econometrics, excel, software, monthly, date

Is there any way to convert quarterly data to monthly in excel or preferably in STATA?
I 
Next to that, how can I transform dates in excel so as to be recognized by STATA?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cubic Splines to convert quarterly data into monthly. See also the following:
https://columbiaeconomics.com/2010/01/20/how-economists-convert-quarterly-data-into-monthly-cubic-spline-interpolation/

Update: Take a look at the following link too:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/cubic-splines-in-excel-2010/0033ceae-6c6f-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?auth=1